# HTML/CSS hyperlink attributes not working?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, web

(Macbook 10.5.8 with Safari 5.0.6)

I'm a noob at HTML/CSS. So I have this hyperlink and it's not responding to any of the things i write except for "a {}" and "a:link {}". I can't even click it. If I hover over it, nothing happens. It's just static. Here's my code:

`

```
.header{
    width: 100.3%;
    height: 40%;
    z-index:0;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -11.5% -1% 0% -1%;
    }

#headhead {
font-family: "Caneletter Script Personal Use", "Arial";
font-size:70px;
text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
display: block;
color: #ffffff;
position: relative;
margin: 7% 55% 15% 0%;
}

#termsT {
background-color: #adff2f;
border-radius: 15px;
height: 4em;
width: 10em;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
z-index: -2;
margin: -7% 0% 0% 10%;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
z-index: 2;
position: absolute;
margin: 53% 0 0 34%;
font-size: 130%;
color: black;
}

a:link {
color: orange;
}

a:visited {
color: purple;
}

a:hover {
color: white;
text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
color: red;
}

h1 {
text-align: center;
}

p {
margin:0;
text-align: center;
}

.tip {
text-align: left;
}`
```

Here's my html for the hyperlink

```
`<div id="termsT">
    <a href="http://www.google.com">Terms</a>
</div>`
```

And here's the "head" section of my html:

```
    <head>
    {% block stylesheets %}
        {% stylesheets
            '@AcmeWebBundle/Resources/public/css/song.css'
        %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" />
        {% endstylesheets %}
    {% endblock %}
    <title>President's Song (Animaniacs)</title>
</head>
```

I just made all of them different colors just to see it work. Right now, the hyperlink is orange, size 130%, in the designated margin, and has no underline.

UPDATE: Some people wanted my entire css code, so I posted it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55861/discussion-between-buddhistbeast-and-gretta).

Comment: If anyone's curious, I found my solution here: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Answer (score 1):

I wonder, why you have given the z-index value as -1. remove the z-index value and try.

Comment: yeah, your problem describes what is expected to happen when you have a negative z-index.

Comment: I removed the z-index. Now it turned purple and I still can't click it. It's static.

Answer (score 0):

Your anchor is covered up by the container

http://jsfiddle.net/3yPUs/

```
<div>asdasd
    <a href="#">sdfds</a>
</div>
```

I am only guessing that the container div is actually containing the anchor. Since you have z-index set to -1. You are not actually hovering the anchor. Remove the negative z-index and it will be fixed

Update: since the given code works by itself http://jsfiddle.net/3yPUs/1/ you must have other stuff that's on top of the anchor or the container div in this case which is covering it up so you can't hover it

Comment: @Gretta `<a href=...>` is an anchor https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: I removed the anchor. It turned purple and it's still static.

Comment: Ok so I removed the container(div) and it appears to work. But how do I make it so that it works when it's on top of the div? I removed the z-index like you told me to but it's still not working.

Comment: @Gretta You have negative z-index on the container as well as the anchor. It is not possible for me to give you a 100% solution because I don't know what your page layout is, and what is required for the ideal result. Right now, I don't know which z-index you removed and what else you have on the page that could be effecting the result. If you can create a http://jsfiddle.net then maybe we can get somewhere

Comment: it's fine actually. i feel like the problem is that i have a really old system and old browser, so some of the things aren't working. (http://jsfiddle.net/dQr7g/2/) That link is a jsfiddle that someone made and it doesn't work for me.